# QGIS graduated symbol binning

Tags: qgis

Im trying to understand how QGIS creates bins of data when using graduated symbols. For example if I create a symbol with 2 classes and the values are 1-2 and 2-3. What will happen with a feature with a value of 2? In what bin will it go?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4):

The interval is (a, b], or a < x <= b.

As seen below, 1.0 belongs to Brown 0.50 - 1.00, but not to Pink 1.00 - 1.50.

The 2.00 is in the Blue group.

[image]

To answer your question; 2 goes to the bin of value 1-2.